# Where does node file system (fs.writeFile) writes to on default in Meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am using the fs.writeFile method in the following way:

```
        fs = require('fs');
        fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node.js', (err) => {
            console.log('It\'s saved!');

            fs.readFile('message.txt', function (data) {

                console.log("Asynchronous read: " + data.toString());
            });
        });
```

**output:**

```
It's saved!
Asynchronous read: Hello Node.js
```

Since I receive the expected output, I assume that the file `message.txt` is created somewhere, and I am actually writing and reading to/from it. But I can not find it anywhere on my system. So where is `message.txt` created?

I am using Meteor.js

Comment: The file is created in the current working directory. From the docs: *"The relative path to a filename can be used. Remember, however, that this path will be relative to `process.cwd()`."* https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system

Comment: I would expect that too, but it is not there. I even can not find it trough the search in the finder. If i search for message.txt, it finds only my app.js file, with the code of fs.writeFile

Comment: How do you run it? I assume you use some IDE (Im sure you would find the file if you ran it from command line)

Comment: Just out of curiosity what does `fs = Npm.require('fs');` do and why not just `var fs = require('fs');`?

Comment: @Michael: very good question, obviously it does nothing, I just copy pasted that from a tutorial, I thought that I need to go this approach, since I am using Meteor.js. but var fs = require('fs'); is enough

Comment: @Felix Kling: Thanks, that helped. I answered to this question myself, but if you want you can copy that answer and I will accept yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the file by using the command `process.cwd()` in my console.

Since I am using Meteor.js, the file is saved on default to:

```
../.meteor/local/build/programs/server
```

Comment: I would advise against relying on this location. A better approach is to use settings value or environment variable to specify the absolute path of where to read/write files.